# Переливка данных с MS SQL в postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sql-server

Есть задача перелить данные с MS SQL в Postgresql. В некоторых таблицах может быть 100 млн. строк. Какие инструменты для этого можно использовать? Схемы БД различаются. Слышал, что при использовании CSV файлов уже при 30к записей могут быть трудности.

Comment: Какого рода трудности?

Comment: *Слышал, что при использовании CSV файлов уже при 30к записей могут быть трудности.* Врут.

Answer (score 0):

Для как разовой акции, так и многократной (постоянной), советую на MS SQL Server установить драйвер ODBC для PostgreSQL как указанно в инструкции:

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-a-postgresql-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver16

Ну а потом настраиваем "джобик" и переносим данные с SQL Server на PostgreSQL по кд или триггером, если прям в реальном времени хотите получать актуальные данные.